# Banco de dados SQL Azure recusando conexão

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, microsoft-azure

Estou com problemas para conectar a base de dados SQL Azure através de uma aplicação web publicada neste endereço:

http://timesheetacs.azurewebsites.net/Login/Login

Esta é a string de conexão:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.csdl|res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.ssdl|res://*/Context.ControleHorasContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=srvdbacs2.database.windows.net;initial catalog=dbTimesheet;persist security info=True;user id=acensao@srvdbacs2;password=####;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Ao tentar efetuar a conexão dispara este erro:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

Mas ao tentar conectar pelo SQL Management Studio, funciona perfeitamente.

Eu também tentei conectar debugar a aplicação local apontando para o banco de dados azure para encontrar erros, mas simplesmente não dispara erros. 
O erro só esta ocorrendo no ambiente da Azure.

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: confere sua Connection string

Answer (score 1):

Sua connection string realmente está bem confusa. De uma olhada nela se não tem informação demais.

O padrão de connection string para Azure SQL é

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

Substitua por essa e veja se o problema é resolvido.